# How to perform Linq to Entites Left Outer Join

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, left-join

I have read plenty of blog posts and have yet to find a clear and simple example of how to perform a LEFT OUTER JOIN between two tables.  The Wikipedia article on joins [Join (SQL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) provides this simple model:

```
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
`LastName` varchar(25),
`DepartmentID` int(4),
UNIQUE KEY `LastName` (`LastName`)
);

CREATE TABLE `department` (
`DepartmentID` int(4),
`DepartmentName` varchar(25),
UNIQUE KEY `DepartmentID` (`DepartmentID`)
);
```

Assume we had a EmployeeSet as an employee container `ObjectSet<Employee> EmployeeSet` and a DepartmentSet `ObjectSet<Department> DepartmentSet`.  How would you perform the following query using Linq?

```
SELECT LastName, DepartmentName
FROM employee e 
  LEFT JOIN department d 
    ON e.DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `DefaultIfEmpty` method :

```
var query =
    from e in db.EmployeeSet
    join d in db.DepartmentSet on e.DepartmentID equals d.DepartmentID into temp
    from d in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { Employee = e, Department = d };
```

Comment: I wanted to give you both +1 for useful answers but didn't realize that I was limited in voting.  This answer is more generic and allows for a right outer join which was something I also needed to do in my application code.  Could you explain what is happening on the line 'from d in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()'?

Comment: `DefaultIfEmpty` returns a sequence containing a single element with the default value (null in that case) if the input sequence is empty. So, if there is no Department that matches the DepartmentID of the employee, `temp.DefaultIfEmpty()` only contains null. The second `from` clause associates each element of `db.EmployeeSet` with each element of `temp.DefaultIfEmpty()`

Answer (score 1):

I would write this, which is *far* simpler than `join` and [does exactly the same thing](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/01/13/38525/):

```
var q = from e in db.EmployeeSet
        select new 
        {
            LastName = e.LastName,
            DepartmentName = e.Department.DepartmentName
        };
```

Comment: This answer is 'cleaner' but requires a relationship between employee and department.

Comment: You don't have a foreign key?!?

Comment: what you're doing is not an outer join... According to the original SQL query, `e.Department` could be null, so your code could cause a `NullReferenceException`

Comment: @Thomas, that is completely wrong. LINQ to Entities coalesces nulls, unlike to LINQ to objects. Try it yourself. L2E and L2O have different rules. You will *never* see a `NullReferenceException` in a purely L2E query.

Comment: good to know... I didn't know that. Now that I think of it, it makes sense, since the projection is also done in SQL